# How Can i write a java code which scan a document from scanner and shows me?

Tags: java, swing, jtree

How Can i write a java code which scan a document from scanner and shows me in java tree. When i click scan, it scans domucemts on my scanner and shows me in the window. How can i write this? Is there any code example?

Comment: You would normally use OCR to understand *text* from an image (or scan) but you have information in the form of a tree?  Is it an Oak tree?  ;)  What sort of tree?  I suspect you should start on much simpler things.

Comment: No I dont use OCR , it only scan as a image when i click scan button and , shows me in the window. It semms simple, but i dont know how can i do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This task you are planning is very complex if you want to build the whole application by yourself. 
But with help of third-party tools you can do it with few lines of code.
Steps:

1. Use the software the came with the scanner or any other third party tools to scanner the document into pdf format.
2. Use another software/library to extract text from pdf. As I googled, came across PDFBox API.

   > PDFBox is a library which can handle different types of PDF documents
   >   including encrypted PDF formats and extracts text and has a command
   >   line utility as well to convert PDF to text documents.

   Example of using the API [here](http://www.prasannatech.net/2009/01/convert-pdf-text-parser-java-api-pdfbox.html)
3. Modify the class above or write a new class that will read the text file and construct the tree structure.

Comment: I am saying again, I am not try to convert pdf to text file; It is simple, I want to scan image from my scanner and show me it in java tree. But you insist on telling me converting image to text file! I m going to say again I dont want to convert image to text file; I want to make simple scanner program, Could you show me the way; How can I do it? I am new in the stackoverflow.

Comment: What will you suggest if I don't want to use any third party tools and want to build everything on my own? What resources should I refer to, can you please help?